# How to really define what a "helper" is?

Tags: helper

How can we really say "Here it is, the class I just developed is a helper!"

Would the class have some special criteria? I have a class in Java that exporta my JTables into CVS Files. Is it a helper? I also use a class to validate my forms. Is it a helper?

I hear this term often, but I realize that I don't really know what is it.

Comment: It is usually used synonymously with "Utility", but you might simply add either word to the class name. Post your specific code if you want us to classify it for you.

Comment: It's pretty much anything you want it to be, though in general it would not "stand alone" but would be used in conjunction with some other (relatively specific) piece of code.

Comment: In my opinion, helpers are the classes that help another class do its job, but they are not important to another class. If the class is capable of doing something meaningful on its own, it's not a helper class.

Comment: (It is important that you don't read too much into the term.  The general meaning is generally understood, but it subject to a broad range of specific interpretations.  (IOW, the definition is not worth arguing over, nor is it to be trusted -- it' just "informational".)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a 'textbook' definition of what a helper is, but I think most people would define a helper Class as one that makes no sense on its own - in other words, a Class whose whole purpose of existence it to 'help' make some operation on another class easier to do.

For example, if you create a class that follows the 'Adapter' pattern (i.e. it wraps an object of type 'foo' and lets it be used where normally you can only use type 'bar',) I think that adapter class could loosely be called a 'helper' class as well.

Comment: So, an helper would be a class full of "I don't where to put this useful function, so I will put it here" ?

Comment: I guess that's actually a different kind of helper class, but yes. For example java.lang.Math contains a bunch of useful static methods and brings them under one umbrella - some people might call that a helper -- I would tend to call that a 'toolkit' or 'utility' class - but like I said, it's not a well-defined term.

Answer (score 2):

A helper class is a class  that is used only by another class to complete a function. Thus, the helper has no right or need to be public, and is only created as being private.

For example, Private Class B helps public class A complete a set of tasks, A is calling on B and is of no use on its own.

For example (just a quick write-up, not tested)

```
    private int newInt(String str)
    {
        test = Integer.parseInt(str);
        return test;
    }
```

and it could be called by:

```
    public int transformation(String str)
    {
        return newInt(str);
    }
```

This of course would be a class of its own, which would have to be called in your main class.

Comment: So, in this case you would have to instanciate an object. But what if the clas is full of static function ?

Comment: The helper does not need to be static, the class that is calling it can be static but it really depends on what your use is. If you give me one minute I will edit my answer and give you a quick example.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm beginning to understand. Let's take an other example : In Java, I'm exporting the JTable's data in a CSV file with a class named ExportToCVS. This class is public and the method export is static. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I have never worked with that framework, so to be honest I don't know much about it, however you are saying that the class ExportToCSV is static? If so you can only call it in your main class, and must work with it from there. Do you have errors?

Comment: No no no, there is no errors, the question is "Is my ExportToCSV class a helper class ?"

Comment: No I don't think you would call it a helper method in the traditional sense. It is public, and it is completing a set out task, it is not helping another method complete a task. So in my opinion it is not a helper method.

Answer (score 1):

From some of the quick research I did, and my own personal experience when dealing with helper classes (.Net and Java), a helper class, is a class that provides functionality that is not actually relevant to the code one is developing, but rather provides some boilerplate work, such as casting, converting datatypes, or performing some common mathematical functions, for instance.

Such code can be generally reused in other projects, to further facilitate work being done.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything helps should be a helper, a class wouldn't even exist if it didn't 'help' something. Usually helper classes offer shortcuts, like sql helpers. I think they should be something spesific and contain a group of relevant shortcut functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think a "helper" class is a class which has been created only to support another classes on their functions.

There are a lot of cases where you need to create a "helper" class to put on it some methods that they do some functions. Some examples would be a class that have methods to calculate holidays on a year or transform some fields or formats in another.

Another example could be when you have to develop an app that it has a progress bar. You can create a "helper" class only for manage the progress bar (setting texts, calculating times, providing estimations...).

If you divide your app on layers (GUI, Business, DAO, etc.), it's interesting to have some "helper" or "utility" class (or classes) to do some tasks that you need to do but that they don't belong to GUI, business or DAO (Data Access Objects) layers explicitly. In this case, you could have an utility class for each layer and put inside the auxiliary methods that you need.